# Rotate a rect about an arc in java swing

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I want to move this small rectangle about the circumference of the circle, so that I looks and moves like a canon.

[image]

**Code**

```
private void doDrawing(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillArc(-CANON_RADIUS/2, this.getHeight()-CANON_RADIUS/2, CANON_RADIUS, CANON_RADIUS, 0, 90);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(CANON_RADIUS/2, this.getHeight()-CANON_RADIUS/2, CANON_WIDTH, CANON_HEIGHT);
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(-60), rect.getX() + rect.width/2, rect.getY() + rect.height/2);
    Shape transformed = transform.createTransformedShape(rect);
    g2d.fill(transformed);
}
```

This code rotates rectangle about its centre. How can I rotate rectangle around the circumference?

Comment: Show the rest of the code too, so we can help you. I think given what you have there may not be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you can use a transformation matrix for this, like you are already using:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Edit:
looking at your code, you want to rotate your canon around an anchor. Please look at the javadocs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html

> public void rotate(double theta,
>             double anchorx,
>             double anchory)

the first argument is your rotation, the last two arguments have to be the middle of your cannon base! like screen.height and 0 for your example:

```
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(-60), 0, Screen.height);
Shape transformed = transform.createTransformedShape(rect);
g2d.fill(transformed);
```

second approach could be move the middle of your rotated rectangle around the radius of your base.

like (pseudocode):

```
Point p = circle.getPoint();
shape.moveto(p.x-(shape.width/2),p.y-(shape.height/2));
g2d.fill(shape);
```